# Functions are also objects?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

Object() is a constructor function, so I was wondering how come we can call functions on the Object constructor function, for example: Object.create().

In one context, Object seems to be a constructor function for creating objects, in another sense it seems to be an object itself that has methods and properties we can call.

Comment: This is/are called `static` properties or methods. You can research it :) Basically this are methods/properties which are accessible without having an object of the given type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you call a constructor is more primitively put *a function.* Functions are objects as well in Javascript. As such, they can have properties. Properties can be functions:

```
function Object() {}

Object.create = function () {};
```

All functions in Javascript exhibit this trait already:

```
function foo() {}

foo.call(bar);  # <- property .call of function object is a function
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, I get it now :) You rock deceze!